# jquery ajax progress deferred

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been working on an ajax file loader that uses html5 and the latest version of jquery. I'm confused regarding the use of the progress callback with the new promise based ajax. For example, the notify function. Is it called automatically? Or do I need to write a handler for it. In my current code...an excerpt obviously. The progress callback is never hit. I also realize that there are plugins available, but I can't use them.

```
var ajaxFileUpload = new $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"/popup/file_upload.php",
            data:_private.appendFormData(file),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false

        }).progress(function (event) {
                console.log(event);
            })
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log("done");


            })
            .fail(function (event) {
                console.log("fail");
            })}};
```

Comment: Maybe you can't use them but you could study their source

Comment: I have yet to see an example of progress being used with the new promise based ajax in jquery. If anyone has a link...i'm on it

Comment: As far as I'm aware the jquery.ajax doesn't call notify on the deferred at all.  You'd need to create your own xmlhttprequest2 or use  COMET or a pulling service if the progress is dependent on server processing and not upload/download time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Upload Progress

If you want a progress bar on upload you can look at https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js lines 292-309 (it's a jquery plugin, but you could just pull out that small bit for your use without a plugin).

```
s.xhr = function() {
    var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    if (xhr.upload) {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            var percent = 0;
            var position = event.loaded || event.position;
            var total = event.total;
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
            }
            options.uploadProgress(event, position, total, percent);
        }, false);
    }
    return xhr;
};
```

## Download Progress

If you want a progress bar on download you can look at http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/ for example code.  Your server must give the `Content-Length` on the response header for that to work I believe.

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById("p"),
  client = new XMLHttpRequest()
client.open("GET", "magical-unicorns")
client.onprogress = function(pe) {
if(pe.lengthComputable) {
  progressBar.max = pe.total
  progressBar.value = pe.loaded
}
}
client.onloadend = function(pe) {
progressBar.value = pe.loaded
}
client.send()
```

## Server Progress

If you are running a report that takes a while and you want the progress of the server processing, might I suggest changing it to be multiple ajax requests: `beginFoo`, `getFooProgress`, `getFooResult`.  Other methods include using a COMET or Websocket connection to communicate progress from the server, or a seperate pulling webservice while the initial ajax request waits for a response.

## Note: cool new <progress> element in html5

If you want a progress html5 element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress .

Answer (score 3):

I found this on GitHub to get the [XHR2 progress event in jQuery,](https://gist.github.com/nebirhos/3892018) with upload and download callbacks:

```
(function addXhrProgressEvent($) {
    var originalXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
    $.ajaxSetup({
        xhr: function() {
            var req = originalXhr(), that = this;
            if (req) {
                if (typeof req.addEventListener == "function" && that.progress !== undefined) {
                    req.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                        that.progress(evt);
                    }, false);
                }
                if (typeof req.upload == "object" && that.progressUpload !== undefined) {
                    req.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                        that.progressUpload(evt);
                    }, false);
                }
            }
            return req;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);



// usage:
// note, if testing locally, size of file needs to be large enough
// to allow time for events to fire

$.ajax({
    url: "./json.js",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function() { console.log("Completed."); },
    progress: function(evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            console.log("Loaded " + parseInt( (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100), 10) + "%");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Length not computable.");
        }
    },
    progressUpload: function(evt) {
      // See above
    }
});
```

With a bit of work it can be adapted to call the `.progress()` deferred callback rather than the callback specified in the settings object.

Comment: Can you please show how to make this fire the deferred's progress?

Answer (score 3):

Good option is to rewrite your ajax function with a custom Deferred, so you can supply the progress method with updates from $.Deferred.notify(). You might do something like this:

```
function doAjax() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"/popup/file_upload.php",
    success: deferred.resolve,  // resolve it 
    error: deferred.reject,  // reject it
    xhrFields: {
      onprogress: function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          deferred.notify(parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100), 10);  // notify as a factor of the event object
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return deferred.promise();
}

doAjax()
  .done(function(data) {})
  .fail(function() {} ) 
  .progress(function(value) {  // notify value is available as the param
    console.log('Progress: ', value + "%");  // output
  }
);
```

Output this to text or populate the HTML5 progress element http://jsbin.com/wevolosa/2/edit?html,console,output