# jQuery.ajax - possible to fire two success callbacks per ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm trying to display two progress bars for multiple ajax requests. One progress bar reaches 100% each time one of my 18 ajax requests is complete and another reaches 100% when all 18 requests are complete. The first bar works great and is implemented in my ajax success callback. I'm having trouble triggering my second bar because it seems I need a second success callback...

Here is the code for my first ajax requests. It gets called 18 times because that is how many items are in my Config object.

```
for (var propt in Config) {

    var db = '...';
    var user = '...';
    var pword = '...';
    var func = '...';
    var dat = {"...": propt };
    var url = "https://...";

    var callData = jQuery.extend({"Db": db, "User": user, "Password": pword, "Function": func}, dat);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(callData),
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
                    var percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;
                    //Do something with download progress
                            tableProgressBar(percentComplete);
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success: successHandlerRunTest1,
        error: errorHandlerRunTest1,
        dataType: "json"
    });
    $('#jsonMsg1').html('Running...');
    $('#jsonRslt1').html(' ');
}
```

I would also like to fire this success function simultaneously.

```
success : function (serverResponse) {
    response[response.length] = serverResponse;
    $('#progress-bar').text(current + ' of ' + total + ' tables are done');
    current++;
},
```

Unfortunately I don't believe I can call the second success function from within the first success function because the first receives special parameters containing JSON data.

I've tried something like...

```
success : function (serverResponse) {
    response[response.length] = serverResponse;
    $('#progress-bar').text(current + ' of ' + total + ' tables are done');
    current++;

    successHandlerRunTest1(data);
},
```

...but this doesn't work because the "data" object that my successHandlerRunTest1(data) receives is empty.

Is there a way to perform two success callbacks per ajax request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the `success` parameter.

Use the [`done` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) to attach callbacks, as it returns the promise for chaining you can call it multiple times:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(callData),
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
            var percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;
            tableProgressBar(percentComplete);
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(successHandlerRunTest1)
.fail(errorHandlerRunTest1)
.done(function (serverResponse) {
    response[response.length] = serverResponse;
    $('#progress-bar').text(current + ' of ' + total + ' tables are done');
    current++;
});
```

Comment: Could also utilize `deferred.progress` within `.then()` pattern, i.e.g., `.then(fn /* done */, fn /* fail */, fn /* progress */)` ? Thanks

Comment: [Yes, that seems to be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19639961/1048572) (and indeed favourable over mixing the callback into the listener setup)

Comment: Interesting. Appear that `jQuery.ajax()` `jqxhr` (`deferred`)  object not possess `notify` property , callback ? though `progress` callback present ; neither documented at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax ? see  notify status mentioned at recent comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971676/notify-after-async-task-is-done#comment38819796_24973026 . Any illumination as to why progress part of ajax jqxhr ? not appear to include corresponding  `.notify` , documentation ? piece attempts sync pattern of `.notify` , `progress`, `jqxhr` http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/N6EgU Thanks

Comment: Both are [documented for deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). jQxhr objects are promises, not deferreds, they don't have `resolve` or `reject` methods either. It's not mentioned in the $.ajax docs because progress notifications are not used by it, as you know it doesn't even support XHR2.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply pass both callbacks inside the original success callback. Then use `.apply` to pass the same arguments as the success callback was originally called with.

```
success: function()
{
    callbackOne.apply(this, arguments);
    callbackTwo.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

see [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

see [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) property.

Also as a side note never ever put database usernames and passwords in javascript. Since anybody can access it.

Answer (score 1):

Try (this pattern) , utilizing `deferred.always()`

html

```
<progress id="p1" max="1" value="0"></progress>
<progress id="p2" max="17" value="0"></progress>
<span id="jsonMsg1"></span>
<span id="progress-bar"></span>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    var count = null;
    var Config = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
    for (var propt in Config) {

        var db = '...';
        var user = '...';
        var pword = '...';
        var func = '...';
        var dat = {
            "...": propt
        };
        var url = "/echo/json/";

        var callData = jQuery.extend({
            "Db": db,
            "User": user,
            "Password": pword,
            "Function": func
        }, dat);
        var successHandlerRunTest1 = function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            // Do something with download progress
            $("#p1").val(1);
        };
        var response = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(callData)
            },
            beforeSend: function (jqxhr, setiings) {
                jqxhr.count = ++count;
                // Do something with download progress
                $("#p1").val(0);
            },
            /*
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
                    var percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;
                    //Do something with download progress
                            tableProgressBar(percentComplete);
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        */
            success: successHandlerRunTest1,
            error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown)
            },
            dataType: "json"
        })
            .always(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

            $('#jsonMsg1').html('Running...');
            response[response.length] = data;
            $("#progress-bar")
                .text(Number(data["..."]) 
                + ' of ' 
                + Config.length + ' tables are done');
            $("#p2").val(Number(data["..."]));
            // Do something with download progress
            if (data["..."] === "17" && jqxhr.count === 18) {

                console.log(data["..."]);
                $('#jsonMsg1').html('Done...');
                $("#progress-bar")
                    .text(Number(data["..."]) + 1 
                    + ' of ' 
                    + Config.length + ' tables are done');

            };
        });
        // $('#jsonRslt1').html(' ');
    };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/z6DzF/4/

See

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/